# Show number of results Directorypress listing tags Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I would like to show the number of search results found for a directory listing tag. I'm thinking I need something like...

```
<?php echo tag_num_results ('Mayo') ?>
```

(This doesn't work)... I just don't know what I should use instead of tag_num_results. Would anyone with some experience using directorypress know what I should be using instead?

Alternatively,

On this page http://wherestheauction.com/tag/mayo/ it displays exactly what I want, as in "8 Results Found". Would anyone know where this code would be in the directorypress folders? I've searched and searched but still can't find it!

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT

I want the tag search results to appear within the map on this page: http://wherestheauction.com/

So I've got an unordered list

```
<ul id="continents">

<li id="leitrim"><a href="http://wherestheauction.com/tag/leitrim/"><span>Leitrim</span></a></li>
<li id="sligo"><a href="http://wherestheauction.com/tag/sligo/"><span>Sligo</span></a></li>
<li id="roscommon"><a href="http://wherestheauction.com/tag/roscommon/"><span>Roscommon</span></a></li>
<li id="mayo"><a href="http://wherestheauction.com/tag/mayo/"><span>Mayo</span></a></li>
<li id="galway"><a href="http://wherestheauction.com/tag/galway/"><span>Galway</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

When the user hovers over a specific part of the map I want it to say eg "Mayo 8 Auctions".  I'm not sure how to incorporate Ofir Baruch's answer in.

```
$args = array(
                'tag' => $tag,
    );

    $all_posts = get_posts( $args );
    $count = count($all_posts);
    unset($all_posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
        $args = array(
                    'tag' => $tag,
        );

        $all_posts = get_posts( $args );
        $count = count($all_posts);
        unset($all_posts);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How would I go about adding that into my code? I would like it to show up as a hover feature so that it says something like "Mayo 8 Results". My code for this is:
`<li id="mayo"><a href="http://wherestheauction.com/tag/mayo/"><span>Mayo <?php echo $tag('Mayo')?> Results</span></a></li>`

Comment: I didn't understand. please edit your question and add this part (and rephrase it if you can)